# Unable to install Android Studio even after accepting agreement

Tags: android-studio

I just downloaded Android studio. But unable to install it because licence agreement next button is not enabled even after accepting the agreement

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to accept also the extra license to continue

Comment: Where is that one?

Comment: In the “licenses” column select the “intel-Android-extra-license” line and then accept.

Answer (score 0):

click on Intel-android-extra-licence in the list.
and then click accept. you will able to install the android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Select each line item one by one from left side and select Accept Radio Button, then Finish button will enable. Click on the Finnish button. It will start to download all the required software's/patches one by one.